# It's possible to retrieve a payment intent from stripe standard?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using the [Stripe standard connection](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts) I can connect a user and create a payment intent as direct charge like this:

```php
$payment = PaymentIntent::create([
    'amount'   => $amount,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    //'application_fee_amount' => 123,
], [
   'stripe_account' => $stripe_user_id,
]);
```

I saved in my backend the `$payment->id` and the `$payment->client_secret` it's what I need to pay and refund the payments, but I need to retrieve this payment and when I do that the Stripe gives me this error: `Stripe/Error/InvalidRequest with message 'No such payment_intent: pi_asdjaiudaisda`

I'm retrieving the payment like this:

```php
PaymentIntent::retrieve($payment->id);
```

It's like the docs say, but don't look like it's working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like how you are "making API requests on behalf of a Stripe Connect account" by passing `'stripe_account' => $stripe_user_id,` when creating the PaymentIntent

You need to do the same when retrieving the PaymentIntent too.

The reasoning is that this PaymentIntent lives on the Connect account (as it was created there), so you have to make retrieve/update API calls on behalf of the Connect account using `stripe_account` parameter to access that PaymentIntent.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see this flag at the payment intent API docs so I didn't try before. This sure works.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me too! I don't know why the Stripe documentation (https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve) does not mention this. And looking at the JS source code of the API, I could find no 'param' for this. And btw, with the Node API, the param should be `stripeAccount` rather than `stripe_account`.